# Don't understand output of Pandas.Series.from_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three txt files with data,4 columns of numbers.I need to load them to one data frame (dimension [3,n] where n is lenght of column).Becouse I need only one column from each file I decided to use Series.from_csv() function but I cannot comprehend the output.
I have write this code:

```
names = glob.glob("*.txt")
for i in names:
    rank = pd.Series.from_csv(i,sep=" ",index_col = 3)
    print rank
```

And this print me one column of my data(thats good) but also one column filled entire with zeros like this:

```
0.039157    0
0.039001    0
0.038524    0
0.038579    0
0.038385    0
```

What I find more bizzare is when I use

```
rank = pd.Series.from_csv(i,sep=" ",index_col = 3).values
```

I got this:

```
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
```

So its mean that this zeros were values read from files? Then what is the first column from from before?I have tried many method,but I have failed to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use more common [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `delim_whitespace=True` and `usecols` for filtering column, first append all `DataFrames` to `list` `dfs` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = []
names = glob.glob("*.txt")
for i in names:
    rank = pd.read_csv(i,delim_whitespace=True,usecols=[3])
    print rank
    dfs.append(rank)

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Or with `sep='\s+'` - separator is arbitrary whitespace:

```
dfs = []
names = glob.glob("*.txt")
for i in names:
    rank = pd.read_csv(i,sep='\s+',usecols=[3])
    print rank
    dfs.append(rank)

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

You can use also `list comprehension`:

```
files = glob.glob("*.txt")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp, delim_whitespace=True,usecols=[3]) for fp in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```